# Alternative to dirname command that supports spaces

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur, darwin

Consider the following output, when run the command:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

The command `dirname` are not getting right the directory name:

```
$ echo $(dirname $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8))                                                                                     
/Library Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents
```

I think `dirname` nor supports spaces. I'm behind macOS with Big Sur.

Comment: https://shellcheck.net is your friend.

Comment: You rocks @Shawn, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the tip of [@Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn) the solution is simple: just use quotes...

```
$ echo "$(dirname "$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)")"                                                                                
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents
```

Thanks [@Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn)!